# How to find $\int\limits_0^\infty (FC)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The flow and concentration resulting from a rotating disk can be elucidated through the von Kármán similarity solution, which simplifies the Navier-Stokes equations into a set of ordinary differential equations. When uniform suction is applied, the equations become:

$F^2-G^2+ HF′=F′′$ ,
$2FG+HG′=G′′$,
$H′=-2F$ ,
$(Sc)HC′=C′′$ ,

where
$F$=Normalized radial flow , $G$=Normalized tangential flow , $H$=Normalized axial flow and $C$=Normalized concentration , $Sc$=Schmidt number ,$R$=uniform suction , $U$= Velocity of axial flow at infinity. The boundary conditions are:
$F(0)=0$, $G(0)=1$, $H(0)=-R$, $H′(0)=0$, $C(0)=1$,
$F(\infty)=0$ , $G(\infty)=0$ , $H(\infty)=-U$ , $C(\infty)=0$ .
How to find $\int\limits_0^\infty (FC)$

Comment: Are you given $C'(0)$?

Comment: It is given by numerical data

Comment: It's correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your third equation ($H' = -2F$) and multiply it by $Sc\,C$ to get:
\begin{equation}
Sc\, C H'=-2Sc\,FC\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
Now add your fourth equation ($Sc\,HC' = C''$) to Eq. (1) to yield:
\begin{equation}
Sc\, (C H)'=-2Sc\,FC + C''\qquad (2)
\end{equation}
Integrate both sides of Eq. (2) from $0$ to $\infty$:
\begin{align}
Sc \int_0^{\infty}(CH)' &\;=\;-2Sc\int_0^{\infty}FC \;+\; \int_0^{\infty}C''\\
Sc\Bigl(C(\infty)H(\infty) - C(0)H(0)\Bigr)&\;=\;-2Sc\int_0^{\infty}FC \;+\; C'(\infty) - C'(0)
\end{align}
Now apply the boundary conditions $C(\infty) = 0$, $H(\infty)=-U$, $C(0) = 1$, and $H(0) = -R$ and solve for $\int_0^{\infty} FC$ to arrive at:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} FC \;=\; \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{Sc}\bigl(C'(\infty)-C'(0)\bigr) -R\right]
\end{equation}
(Given the conditions of the problem, it seems likely that $C'(\infty) = 0$.)